# Ng-Repeat: Filter By Uniqueness

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Though I have `ui-boostrap` installed, the browser shoots me an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter`

**json objects**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("55b81956fde835be46f22294"), 
"life" : true, 
"domain" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Eukarya" }, 
"kingdom" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Animalia" }, 
"phylum" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Chordata" }, 
"klass" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Mammalia" }, 
"order" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "carnivoria" }, 
"family" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "herpestidae" }, 
"genus" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "galerelaa" }, 
"species" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Mongoose" }, 
"photo" : { "hidden" : true, "url" : "http://room909.com/wp-content/gallery/drawings-by-jared-flynn/snake-v-mongoose-web.jpg" }, 
"__v" : 0 
}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("55b81956fde835be46f22295"), 
"life" : true, 
"domain" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Eukarya" }, 
"kingdom" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Animalia" }, 
"klass" : {"name": "Bivalvia", "hidden": true},
"order" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "Ostreoida" }, 
"family" : {"name": "Ostreidae", "hidden": true},
"genus" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "" }, 
"species" : { "hidden" : true, "name" : "" }, 
"photo" : { "hidden" : true, "url" : "http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/oyster5.jpg" }, 
"__v" : 0 
}
```

**html**

```
<section class="footer">
  <div id="explanation" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="animal in animals | unique: 'animal.domain'" ng-hide="domain" class="panel panel-default">
      <p  class="panel-body">{{animal.domain.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've also tried variations on the unique's value like `domain.name` and `domain`, but they all bring the same error.

Comment: Did you have `angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`?

Comment: What is this `unique` filter you're using? Can you add a link to it? I can't find it in `ui-bootstrap` or `angular`

Comment: Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxJFSw?p=preview) that uses it. I actually just found this now.

Comment: There's another filter library called [a8m](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) that I might give a shot. If it works, I'll come back and explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. All we have to do is, instead, simply installed the wonderful, genius, un-replaceable [a8m](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) angular-filter library with `bower`/`npm`, added to my array of dependencies (@Joy), and used the syntax `ng-repeat="animal in animals | unique: 'domain.name'"` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Unique Filter example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxJFSw?p=preview) will help you using unique filter.  I think version of angular-ui you are using may not have unique filter. try to change the version of ui-bootstrap.

As you see in example, filter accepts property of record item.

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in items | unique:attribute"> 
       <td>{{record.firstName}}</td>
       <td>{{record.lastName}}</td>
       <td>{{record.id}}</td>
       <td>{{record.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

So, in your example it should be as following. See change for ng-hide and unique filter.

```
<section class="footer">
  <div id="explanation" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="animal in zab | unique: 'domain'" 
                ng-hide="animal.domain" class="panel panel-default">
      <p  class="panel-body">{{animal.domain.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```