# "unique" Filter is not working in AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to use below `unique` filter

```
<ng-repeat="feature in allfeatures | unique:'featureName'" value="{{feature.featureName}}">{{feature.featureName}}>
```

But its giving me error like this,

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider%20%3C-%20uniqueFilter

```
<select id="selectFeature" ng-model="features" 
ng-required="true" 
multiple class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().populateAllFeaturesT‌​axonomy(this)" style="width: 200px;"> 
<option ng-repeat="feature in allfeatures | unique:'featureName'" value="{{feature.featureName}}">{{feature.featureName}}</opt‌​ion> 
</select>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. Could you paste some real code?

Comment: <select id="selectFeature" ng-model="features" ng-required="true" multiple class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().populateAllFeaturesTaxonomy(this)" style="width: 200px;">
 <option ng-repeat="feature in allfeatures | unique:'featureName'" value="{{feature.featureName}}">{{feature.featureName}}</option>
 </select>

Comment: You can just edit your post. And secondly you can also use the ng-options directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Where is this unique filter coming from? I don't think this is standard angularjs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832192/angularjs-how-to-get-the-unique-values-in-ng-option ..this is some of link I followed..but still its giving me problem with ng-options for unique values

Comment: Could you post a plunkr? Are you sure you are injecting your Unique filter in your app?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same AngularJs @1.3.15 and ui-bootstrap @0.13.3 and have the same issue. This is likely due to the fact that I'm using such an old version of ui-bootstrap since it is currently @ 1.3.3 when I checked.

They have a fix for it in another [SO post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689360/ng-repeat-filter-by-uniqueness)

Follow the installation guide on angular-filter and make sure you include it in the main app.module folder and index.html.

Here is an example of how I used it:

```
<th> Table Header </th>
<tr ng-repeat="patient in patients | unique: 'patient.name'" >
   <td> {{ patient.name }} , {{ patient.doctor }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In general you should not post link only answers.  Post some relevant code in addition to the link

Comment: Re read it and included what I think would be more helpful :)